# What's the difference between Sorcery and Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, authlogic, sorcery

What is the biggest difference between the Rails Sorcery authentication gem and Authlogic. They both allow you making your own controllers and views. Ryan Bates talks about how he likes Sorcery more than Authlogic, but I can't understand his reasons for this? What do you think of these, I mean what is the biggest difference between them?

Comment: Try them both in a demo project and find out which one you like the best! Asking what the difference is between both seems silly...

Comment: I guess I'm just lazy :(